# Show icon on containing div hover

Tags: css, font-awesome

I want to show the edit icon only when the user hovers over the containing div:

```
<div class="toolbar">
     <span class="pull-xs-right">
           <i class="fa fa-pencil show-on-hover"></i>
           <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
     </span>
</div>
```

The remove icon should still display.

How do I do that with css only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply like this:

```css
.toolbar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.toolbar .show-on-hover {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

.toolbar:hover .show-on-hover {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="toolbar">
     <span class="pull-xs-right">
          <i class="fa fa-pencil show-on-hover"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
     </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, but how do I make it apply to only the icon which has the class "show-on-hover" so that the other icon still displays?

Comment: Edited the post. Is that what you're looking for?